# View the list of SSH connections and view that specific connection using screen

Tags: linux, ssh, display, putty

I have a friend who is connected via SSH, and I would like to view his screen to see his progress in our project and what are the things he's doing. It's like spying on him.

I would like to know how to do this. Currently I can only view the screen that is created by screen command, but how about those screen sessions created during connecting via SSH?

I really need some advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly I believe I have a script that does what you want. See below link :

[SSH Bind Address Script](https://raw.github.com/swys/sshtools/master/bindAddress.sh)

You will need to have `password authorization` turned off and be able to connect via `public key exchange` as well as have `TCP Forwarding` turned on (on the server side, i.e. your friend's computer) for this to work.

Or...

You can do the quick just do the following 1 liner (you will still need `TCP Forwarding : on`). The script is just a connivence since I don't want to keep typing all this in every time when I'm trying to connect to multiple severs or just bind to multiple ports on the same machine.

```
ssh -p $port -N -L $local_port:127.0.0.1:$remote_port $user@$ip
```

- `$port` is the ssh port the remote machine is listening on.
- `$local_port` is the local port on your computer you are going to connect to.
- `$remote_port` is the remote port on your friends computer you will bind your local port to.
- `$user` is the username to use for the ssh connection.
- `$ip` is the ip address ssh will use to connect to.

After you've connected whatever you put for `$local_port` will be a tunnel (through ssh) to your friends remote computer at whatever you put for `$remote_port`.

So if you wanted to view your friend's screen you can point your VNC viewer at `127.0.0.1:$local_port` ($local_port is whatever you put for `$local_port` above).

This assumes that your friend has a VNC server running in the first place of course.